# Cadastro para menores de idade -Php - JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5

Boa tarde galera, então estou criando um cadastro de usuários, porém quero que usuários menores de idade não possam se cadastrar, já tentei de varias formas mais não consegui, se alguém puder me explicar como fazer e me dar um exemplo eu agradeço, preciso que seja em php, então meu formulario está assim...

```html
<?php
session_start();
//apartir daqui faz o cadastro do usuario ao clicar no botão cadastrar que receber o nome de btnCadastrar
$btnCadastrar = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'btnCadastrar', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if($btnCadastrar){
include_once ("conn/conexao.php");
$dados = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);
$dados['senha']= md5($_POST["senha"]);
//aqui insere os dados na tb_usuario
$result_usuario = "INSERT INTO tb_usuario(permissao, nome, dtnasci, email, senha, saldo)VALUES(
 '".$dados['permissao']."',
 '".$dados['nome']."',
 '".$dados['dtnasci']."',
 '".$dados['email']."',
 '".$dados['senha']."',
 '".$dados['saldo']."'
 )";
$resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conexao, $result_usuario) or die (mysqli_error($conexao));
if($resultado_usuario):
 echo "<script>
   alert('Cadastrado Com Sucesso.');
   window.location='login.php';
  </script>"; 
else:
 echo "<script>
   alert('Ocorreu um erro ao cadastrar, entre em contato com o administrador.');
   window.location='login.php';
  </script>";
endif;
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- As 3 meta tags acima *devem* vir em primeiro lugar dentro do `head`; qualquer outro conteúdo deve vir *após* essas tags -->
<title>Lance Web</title>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- HTML5 shim e Respond.js para suporte no IE8 de elementos HTML5 e media queries -->
<!-- ALERTA: Respond.js não funciona se você visualizar uma página file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style type="text/css">
 
 body{ 
  background-color:#0A8AF5;
 }
 
 /*Aqui se move os botões*/
 .botao{
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -15%;
 }
 
 /*fonte da pagina*/
 .font{
  color:white;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
 }
 
 .mover{
  
 }
 
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" align="center" >
    <br><br><img src="img/logo.png" class="img-responsive"><br><br>
     <form class="form-group" action="" method="post">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <label class="font">Nome</label></label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nome" maxlength="50" value="Digite seu nome" onfocus="this.value='';" style="text-align: center;" required><br><br>

    <label class="font">E-mail</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" maxlength="50" value="Digite seu email" onfocus="this.value='';" style="text-align: center;" required><br><br>
   
   
   <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <label class="font">Data de Nascimento</label>
    <input class="form-control dtnasci" type="date" name="dtnasci" maxlength="10" onfocus="this.value='';"  style="text-align: center;" required/><br><br>
   </div>
    
   <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <label class="font">Senha</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="password" name="senha" maxlength="8" style="text-align: center;" required><br><br>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <label class="font">Saldo</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="saldo" required>
        <option>Selecione</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>20</option>
        <option>50</option>
      </select><br><br>
   </div>
   
   <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1"> 
    <a href="index.php"><input class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" type="button" value="Voltar"></a>
   </div>
   
   <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
    <input class="btn btn-info btn-lg submit-botao" type="submit" value="Cadastrar" name="btnCadastrar">
   </div>
   
   </div><!-- fim div para mover a label e os input basta mudar os números no md e no offset -->
  </form><!-- fim do formulario -->
</div><!-- fim div container -->
   
   <!-- jQuery (obrigatório para plugins JavaScript do Bootstrap) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
  $('.dtnasci').on('input',function(){
  var dtnasci = $(this).val();
  var data1 = new Date(dtnasci);
  var data2 = new Date(new Date() - data1);
  var idade = (data2.toISOString().slice(0, 4) - 1970);
  if(idade < 18){
   $('.submit-botao').prop('disabled',true)
   $('.resposta-msg').html('Você não pode se cadastrar').show();
  }else{
   $('.submit-botao').prop('disabled',false);
   $('.resposta-msg').html('').hide();
  }
 })
</script>
<!-- Inclui todos os plugins compilados (abaixo), ou inclua arquivos separadados se necessário -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Coloca o código que você ja fez junto na pergunta, senão não temos como dizer onde você está errando.

Comment: editei e coloquei o formulário, eu apaguei o que tinha feito na data, não funcionava está meio que sem ação

Comment: Você quer que ele verifique na hora que coloque a data, se for menor, não deixar enviar é isso ?

Comment: Tem um erro no seu html `style="text-align: center;"> required/>` Você está fechando o `input` antes do `require`.

Comment: Seria isso AnthraxisBR, na hora que for digitar a data e ver que e menor não envia.

Comment: Obrigado Gabriel Heming

Answer (score 1):

De forma direta, você apenas precisa captar a data de envio, e data de hoje, e calcular a diferença entre as duas:

```js
$('.dtnasci').on('input',function(){
    var dtnasci = $(this).val();
    var hoje = new Date();
    var data1 = new Date(dtnasci);
    var data2 = new Date(hoje - data1);
    var idade = (data2.toISOString().slice(0, 4) - hoje.getFullYear());
    if(idade < 18){
        $('.submit-botao').prop('disabled',true)
        $('.resposta-msg').html('Você não pode se cadastrar').show();
    }else{
        $('.submit-botao').prop('disabled',false);
        $('.resposta-msg').html('').hide();
    }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- As 3 meta tags acima *devem* vir em primeiro lugar dentro do `head`; qualquer outro conteúdo deve vir *após* essas tags -->
    <title>Lance Web</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- HTML5 shim e Respond.js para suporte no IE8 de elementos HTML5 e media queries -->
    <!-- ALERTA: Respond.js não funciona se você visualizar uma página file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
 <style type="text/css">
  
  body{ 
   background-color:#0A8AF5;
  }
  
  /*Aqui se move os botões*/
  .botao{
   text-align: center;
   margin-top: -15%;
  }
  
  /*fonte da pagina*/
  .font{
   color:white;
   font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
   font-size: 16px;
   text-align: center;
  }
  
  .mover{
   
  }
  
 </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" align="center" >
    <br><br><img src="img/logo.png" class="img-responsive"><br><br>
     <form class="form-group" action="" method="post">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
     <label class="font">Nome</label></label>
     <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nome" maxlength="50" value="Digite seu nome" onfocus="this.value='';" style="text-align: center;" required><br><br>

     <label class="font">E-mail</label>
     <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" maxlength="50" value="Digite seu email" onfocus="this.value='';" style="text-align: center;" required><br><br>
    
    
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
     <label class="font">Data de Nascimento</label>
     <input class="form-control dtnasci" type="date" name="dtnasci" maxlength="10" onfocus="this.value='';"  style="text-align: center;" required/><br><br>
    </div>
     
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
     <label class="font">Senha</label>
     <input class="form-control" type="password" name="senha" maxlength="8" style="text-align: center;" required><br><br>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
     <label class="font">Saldo</label>
       <select class="form-control" name="saldo" required>
         <option>Selecione</option>
         <option>5</option>
         <option>10</option>
         <option>20</option>
         <option>50</option>
       </select><br><br>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1"> 
     <a href="index.php"><input class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" type="button" value="Voltar"></a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
     <input class="btn btn-info btn-lg submit-botao" type="submit" value="Cadastrar" name="btnCadastrar">
    </div>
    
    </div><!-- fim div para mover a label e os input basta mudar os números no md e no offset -->
   </form><!-- fim do formulario -->
 </div><!-- fim div container -->
   
   <!-- jQuery (obrigatório para plugins JavaScript do Bootstrap) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Inclui todos os plugins compilados (abaixo), ou inclua arquivos separadados se necessário -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Referência original:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17732897/difference-between-two-dates-in-years-months-days-in-javascript

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67949/discussion-on-answer-by-anthraxisbr-cadastro-para-menores-de-idade-php-javasc)

Answer (score 0):

É só verificar a diferença entre a data de nascimento que o usuário tentou cadastrar e a data atual:

```
$dataBR = "03/07/1994";
$dataConvert = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dataBR));
$dateStart = new DateTime($dataConvert);
$dateNow   = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));

$dateDiff = $dateStart->diff($dateNow);
echo $dateDiff->y;
```

Usando apenas Javascript, você pode usar essa função:

```
function calcularIdade(aniversario) {
    var nascimento = aniversario.split("/");
    var dataNascimento = new Date(parseInt(nascimento[2], 10),
    parseInt(nascimento[1], 10) - 1,
    parseInt(nascimento[0], 10));

    var diferenca = Date.now() -  dataNascimento.getTime();
    var idade = new Date(diferenca);

    return Math.abs(idade.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kodrw5sj/

Comment: blz, mais a onde eu coloco no meu código, para que na hora que o usuário digitar a senha e for menor ele não deixar enviar?

Comment: Utilize `DateTime::createFromFormat` ao invés de usar as funções `date` e `strtotime` desnecessariamente.

Comment: Gabriel, teria como você me da um exemplo, porque meu professor me disse para usar em um _POST, dessa maneira que estão falando não sei como fazer com que o usuário não cadastre ao ser menor de idade.

Comment: entendi, como faço isso em javascript? porque não tenho nenhuma noção... Desculpa e que estou começando a programar agora